# Insert into select with a hard coded value with Ruby Sequel

Tags: ruby, amazon-redshift, sequel

I am using Ruby Sequel to move data into reporting tables daily. I am consolidating data from three tables into a single table. I am doing this in Redshift so I have to use `disable_insert_returning`.  The names of the columns in the two tables match each other but not the end table which means I am using `graph` and `set_graph_aliases`.

```
reports = db[:reports]
report_columns = [:user_id, :purchase_date, :sku]

spoons_select_graph = {
  user_id: :users,
  purchase_date: :spoon_receipts,
  product_id: :spoon_receipts
}
spoons = db[:spoon_receipts]
spoons_select = spoons.graph(:users, user_id: :user_id).set_graph_aliases(spoons_select_graph)

forks_select_graph = {
  user_id: :users,
  purchase_date: :fork_receipts,
  product_id: :fork_receipts
}
forks = db[:fork_receipts]
forks_select = forks.graph(:users, user_id: :user_id).set_graph_aliases(forks_select_graph)

reports.disable_insert_returning.insert(report_columns, spoons_select)
reports.where(channel: nil).update(channel: 'spoons')
reports.disable_insert_returning.insert(report_columns, forks_select)
reports.where(channel: nil).update(channel: 'forks')
```

The updates are taking forever. What I would like to do is add the channel to the `insert select` so that I don't have to go back and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide an executable setup, so I haven't tested this, but I think it will work. The basic idea is to just add a constant column of results to your select.

```
reports = db[:reports]
report_columns = [:user_id, :purchase_date, :sku, :channel]

spoons_select_graph = {
  user_id: :users,
  purchase_date: :spoon_receipts,
  product_id: :spoon_receipts,
  channel: [:spoon_receipts, :channel, 'spoons']
}
spoons = db[:spoon_receipts]
spoons_select = spoons.graph(:users, user_id: :user_id).set_graph_aliases(spoons_select_graph)

reports.disable_insert_returning.insert(report_columns, spoons_select)
```

See the documentation for [`set_graph_aliases`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-set_graph_aliases) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! I missed this in the documentation!

Comment: @Sixty4Bit thank you for the bounty and I'm glad I could help. Please also mark the answer as accepted (click the big checkmark) so that when the question shows up in future searches, people see it has an accepted answer.

Comment: you would think awarding the bounty would have accepted the answer as well. Odd. Thanks for the heads up.